# How can I send command line options to my dockerized program that I start with "docker-compose up"?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, fig, docker-compose

I am trying to use `docker-compose up` the way you can use `docker run [APP_CONTAINER_NAME] [APP_OPTIONS]`.

Comment: I don't really understand the question - in docker-compose you put your arguments in the docker-compose.yml file. Is there a problem with that approach for you?

Comment: @AdrianMouat Yes it's not ideal because everytime you want to send a new option you have to modify the docker-compose.yml, rebuild and rerun. I would like to be able to send options to my program when I run the service as I am able to do when I run the main container with `docker run` and use ENTRYPOINT in my Dockerfile in order to achieve this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The point of Docker Compose is that you don't have to remember all your command line switches.

If you want to change environment variables for different contexts, I suggest you create a base `common.yml` file for Compose. You can then create a new yml file for each different context, inheriting from the `common.yml` file with the `extends` instruction. You can then use the `-f` flag to `docker compose` to switch between contexts.

Also note that Compose should not "rebuild" anything if you just change a variable in the yml, and that you can use an external file for environment variables if that works better for you.

Answer (score 2):

[docker run](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/) is defined as:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

While [`docker compose run`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/5dca6c232e9a57b6bca2d72e6007f56d392a0001/compose/cli/main.py#L270) is defined as:

```
docker-compose run [options] [-e KEY=VAL...] SERVICE [COMMAND] [ARGS...]
```

In both cases, the final `ARGS` (which could be the "`APP_OPTIONS`" of the OP's question) will be passed to the container command.

Note that some of the `docker run` option can be used as is in `docker-compose run` (lie a `-d`, to run the container command detached), but not all of them.

Comment: Isn't there any way to put the ARGS into the docker-compose file? Passing them on the command line is too volatile in my case.

Comment: @dsteinkopf Sure: with 'command' (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) you can override the image default command, allowing you to repeat the command defined in the image, but change its parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the Dockerfile and see what is handling the APP_OPTIONS. Chances are that the ENTRYPOINT is taking the option flags. In this case, specify the command to send to the entrypoint using

```
command: [-flag1, -flag2]
```

This works because the COMMAND in the Dockerfile acts as default args to the entrypoint when both are specified https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/